# Calcular el importe total de un negocio. Con -1 se finaliza el programa. Mi problema es que me da el importe total menos 1

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo python y realmente no sé por qué me da el total restado a -1:
ejemplo la sumatoria de las ventas es : $1500 y mi resultado es $1499

```
ventas = float(0)
contador = -1
suma = float(0) 


while ventas != -1: 

   ventas = float(input("Ingrese el importe de venta: "))
   
   suma = suma +  ventas 
   contador += 1
   

if contador == -1:
    print("no")
else:
    print("El importe total es de: $", suma)
    print("Se realizaron", contador, "ventas en el día")
```

Comment: ¿Está bien indentado tu código?

Comment: Puede que al pegar el código no lo hice correctamente es mi primera pregunta en stackoverflow. Ya la arreglo.

Comment: Al ingresar el último dato (el que _rompe_ el while), también computa ese último dato. Sencillamente validá el valor que ingresaste antes de sumarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencillo. Le estás poniendo de terminación al ingreso de ventas el `-1`, PERO en tu while estás validando **el valor anterior**. Si el valor anterior no fue -1, vuelves y lo pides, recibes -1, se lo sumas a la suma y lueeeego validas otra vez.

Añade una validación

```
ventas = float(0)
contador = -1
suma = float(0)

while ventas != -1:

   ventas = float(input("Ingrese el importe de venta: "))
   if ventas != -1:
      suma = suma +  ventas
      contador += 1

if contador == -1:
    print("no")
else:
    print("El importe total es de: $", suma)
    print("Se realizaron", contador, "ventas en el día")
```

Comment: Perfecto. Solucionado. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Lo que pasa es que también está sumando el "-1", puedes solucionarlo al final del while sumándole nuevamente un "1" o en el mismo bucle.

Comment: Lo mejor es responder mostrando el código correcto, y una ejecución que demuestre la solución.